# how to get data from commands in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
 cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(userName)
        
 cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(email)
        
 cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type(password)
```

how to get userName, email, password data?

in cypress
where:

userName

email

password

are generated randomly

what am i talking about

the code generate random values of : login password and email by using faker and type them on register page fields and register a new user and logged out after

i need to get that random values which was used in previous step and type them into login fields on log in page (to log in like registered user)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to check that the text has been properly "typed" into the input fields, but here you go:

```
 cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').should('have.text', userName);
```

Comment: I don't thing this will help

Answer (score 0):

Install faker js using `npm install --save-dev @faker-js/faker` and in your test you can do this:

```js
const faker = require('faker')

describe('Test Suite', () => {
    it('Test Case', () => {
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(faker.internet.userName())
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(faker.internet.email())
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type(faker.internet.password())
    })
})
```

Comment: it is a faker i need to get this fake logs and passes to use on the other page. They are must be the same to this ones

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the data and be able to use it in all of your spec files, you can set that during test startup in your `cypress.config.{js|ts}` file as a Cypress Environment variable.

```js
const { faker } = require('faker'); 
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...
    env: {
      randomData: {
        username: faker.internet.userName(),
        email: faker.internet.email(),
        password: faker.internet.password()
      }
    },
    ...
  },
});

// In your spec file
describe('foo', () => {
  it('bar', () => {
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(Cypress.env('randomData').username)
  });
});
```

Comment: it_won't_help__

Comment: What won't help? What issue does this not solve? What issue are you still having? Adding comments like "it won't help" isn't particularly helpful to those who are posting answers -- it gives us no feedback on _how_ our answers are incorrect.